# In the movie "In Time", has the currency always been "Time"?

Tags: money, in-time

In the movie [*In Time*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Time), almost everything revolves around time, in fact it's the primary form of currency.

Was the world always this way, or was there once a monetary system similar to what we use? If it hasn't always been this way, how long has Time been the primary form of currency?

Comment: My answer on the dupe addresses this. At some point in the future all of humanity was genetically manipulated. Presumably before this point they would have needed to use some other form of currency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It hasn't always been like this, time hasn't always been the primary (if not the only) currency. It became a currency because of the no-aging factor (past the age of 25) in humans. They can't die, but can reproduce, resulting in infinite human beings. So they are implanted with this device, after birth, that ends their life if they run out of time.

Surely, before the aging factor happened, they did have some other form of currency that could or couldn't have been superior to our own.

Comment: It's in the opening monologue. He explains it all.

Comment: @shachna Would you care to clarify, it's been a while since I saw the movie.

Comment: I haven't seen it in awhile as well. So I just re-watched it and all it says is that at some point humans were genetically engineered to stop aging at 25.

Comment: @shachna That's what I thought, and wrote.

Comment: @Shachna: I've watched most of the movie a few times now, but each time I always seem to miss the opening monologue. Which is mainly why I asked the question; I wasn't sure what I was missing and what was explained... Does the opening monologue also explain people being implanted with the device shortly after birth?

Comment: @onewho all it says is people were genetically engineered to stop aging at 25. It does't say anything about a device at all.

Comment: They aren't implanted with it. It's genetically encoded into their bodies.